# Reading txt file with integers of 32 bit precision in python

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, file, jupyter-notebook, precision

I need to read a .txt file with integer values with 32 bit precision in python (python3 to be precise).

The file was created in MATLAB using the following command:

```
fwrite(fileID,array,'*int32')
```

When I read the same file in MATLAB using the command:

```
array = fread(fileID,'*int32')
```

the integers are indeed read in the array variable.

**However**, when I try to read the same file in a Python Jupyter notebook, i can never read the values. More specifically when I use:

```
file = open('path/file.TXT', 'r')
array = file.read()
```

i get the following message:

> /usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
>      319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
>
> 320         data = self.buffer + input
>
> --> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>
> 322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
>
> 323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte

The same message pops up when I use the load function from numpy:

```
array = numpy.loadtxt('path/file.TXT', int)
```

I should note, that when i try to open the file with any text editor in Ubuntu, I can not see the values. Thus I can only read it in MATLAB. I can change the way the file is created  in MATLAB since it is not my part of what I have to do.

I can provide the file if requested. Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: Better export .mat - Files because the import in Python works perfectly. Why do you use a proprietary export command?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by proprietary export command? I don't actually do anything in MATLAB. The MATLAB part is another students work. The data was collected from an FPGA and formatted into this txt file in a MATLAB environment. Then I was handed the data to analyze them, but I am much more comfortable with python than MATLAB so here we are.

Comment: Is it possible to upload this file so that we might be able to inspect it?

Comment: Here you go:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NPf58cJqYyRNQOPuBxVschnXBmCRBX96

If you open the file in MATLAB with the command I posted above, it should give you the actual values.

Comment: @Impulsleistung thank you for your answer, exporting data in a .mat file did the trick for me, as you can see below. If you want you can post this as an answer to get the credit, cause I can't seem to be able to reference you.

Comment: Wait, that looks like a binary file, not text

Comment: It is a binary file, but matlab saves it as a .txt file when you use the code I presented in the question above.

Comment: MATLAB **does not** write ASCII data with the instruction you gave above `fwrite(fileID,array,'*int32')`. The data inside the file will always be binary with this instruction. The **name** of the file might end up as `something.txt` IF you specified that in the file handle when you opened the file (ex: `fileID=fopen('something.txt','w') ;`). But this would be wrong, you'd better create the file with the proper extension from the start : `fileID=fopen('something.bin','w') ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Impulsleistung as per your suggestion I exported the files from MATLAB as a .mat file and used the following code to get the data I needed:

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat('path/data.mat')
array = data.get('array')
```